# I broke and repaired lightdm, was vlc to blame?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, lightdm, vlc

After about 5 hours of poking around my motherboard with a multimeter and adding/removing hardware and tweaking bios settings I have lightdm back! It took a long time to figure out why my computer wouldn't pass the bios screen!

I downloaded a movie last night but the file format wasn't opening in vlc, which I thought was weird because that plays everything. I googled "how to play fileformatX" and then performed the indicated apt-get command. I think I needed vlc, which really struck me as weird because I had vlc and always use it. It was really late at night and I can't remember the apt command.

So I looked in /var/log/apt/history.log and see the lines:

```
Start-Date: 2017-10-14  01:56:17
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-packages' sender=':1.239'
Install: vlc:amd64 (2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4)
End-Date: 2017-10-14  01:56:20
```

I'm currently looking into what that means, but in the mean time it indicates that some daemon installed something that had to do with vlc. It looks weird to me because the majority of the lines in that file have a Commandline like "apt-get install blahblah", which looks like something I would have typed. I also see alot of Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade in the history file.

Anyway, I shutdown the PC last night and turned it on today and it wouldnt go past the BIOS screen! Even weirder, the BIOS screen had changed from the one I'm used to seeing. I have a gigabyte motherboard and I used to see this screen:
[image]

but now I see this one:

[image]

Now that was very surprising!I thought the bios screen should be totally independent of whatever fooling around I do in the OS. After much hardware and software debugging I decided to uninstall lightdm and my nvidia drivers and then reinstall both, and now I'm back up and running and writing you all a message.

But my BIOS screen changed and there used to be a "Display" option if I clicked the unity launcher in the top left. The icon was a computer monitor and it would open up my display settings like screen resolution and the positions of my two monitors, which one was left and which one right. That program is gone now and I have the nvidia display settings program in it's place.

[image]

Does anyone think that our beloved vlc wreaked all this havoc? I'm going to look into what dependencies it installs. I'd like to break everything again by reinstalling vlc however I did, but I don't remember what I typed and it's not in my history because I must have done the install / upgrade via some other installation mechanism. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would imagine your two different BIOS splash screens would correspond to different BIOS versions. As such the new version could only be installed by flashing the BIOS which most manufacturers do with a Windows based .exe. As for the rest of your question I don't use vlc...

Comment: That's why the bios thing is so strange to me! I certainly didn't flash the bios. I think that probably warrants it's own question. I guess I'll open it on superuser.